# Using gestureRecognizer: shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, simultaneous

I'm trying to detect up and down swipes simultaneously on my app. I have a SKScene and I'm adding the gesture recognizer in `func didMoveToView: view`
I have set the delegate: `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`, and have the following func all returning true.

```
gestureRecognizerShouldBegin: gestureRecognizer
gestureRecognizer: shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer
gestureRecognizer: shouldReceiveTouch
```

When I swipe with one finger I can see that `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` is fired and returning true. Func attached to the swipe is working also.

But when I try to swipe in both directions at the same time the corresponding func are not fired and `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` are not fired.

The swipes are working great when I do them separately, but when simultaneously none swipes are executed.

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:

```
class GameControlller: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {}
```

Adding the swipes:

```
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    print("did move to view")
    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameControlller.PaddleMoveUp(_:)))
    swipeDown.direction = .Down
    self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

    let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameControlller.PaddleMoveDown(_:)))
    swipeUp.direction = .Up
    self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
    swipeDown.delegate = self
    swipeUp.delegate = self
}
```

The UIGestureRecognizer delegate func:

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}


 func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    print("Simultaneous gesture recognizer!")
    return true
}
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: The error is probably not in the code you are showing us atm. Please provide more context (more code). You must have made some mistake somewhere else.

Comment: Don't forget to `import QuartzCore`

Comment: Added QuartzCore...no different

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forget set the delegate:

```
swipeUp.delegate = self
swipeDown.delegate = self
```

Comment: I got the delegate now..But no different i behavior